# Crashing When Creating a Process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to use [msdn function (CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)) in C++ in order to run an application. I don't get any errors but when I run it, it crashes. What I did also notice it that it created a process, but it didn't run the text file it was supposed to.

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void createPro ();

int main()
{
    createPro();
}

void createPro () {

    LPCTSTR lpApplicationName = "C:/Users/Andyy/Desktop/hello.txt";

    LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo;
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo;

    memset(&lpStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(lpStartupInfo));
    memset(&lpProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(lpProcessInfo));


    if (!CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,
                   NULL, NULL, NULL,
                   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                   lpStartupInfo,
                   lpProcessInfo
                  )
   ) {
    cout << "Failed to create process" << lpApplicationName << endl;
}

    cout << "Program exec: " << lpApplicationName << endl;
}
```

It creates the process but it fails to run the text file and no errors showed in compilers. Thanks in advance.
Return error: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Your `lpApplicationName` should be a name of an executable. Instead it refers to a text file, and `CreateProcess` probably fails because one cannot execute a text file. Maybe describe by words what are you trying to do?

Comment: "Crashing". No, it doesn't crash. Crashing is the abnormal termination of a process due to an unhandled, uncontained error. Ignoring a return value does not cause termination of the process.

Comment: I tried with an executable and it didn't also work. (Err: Windows Console Command Stopped Working)

Comment: I reverted the edit since it completely changed the question. Lesson to learn: make a [mcve] next time.

Comment: Yeah I wrote this fast but that wasn't very clever of me. I should re-do the post so I can get my error fixed in another post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CreateProcess` is used to create process objects from executable files. You are passing a text file which is not an executable file. Presumably you are actually trying to show the text file in the default text editor. Use `ShellExecuteEx` to do that.

---

Beyond that, you don't allocate the two structs that are needed in your call to `CreateProcess`. Instead you declare pointers to structs, and leave the pointer uninitialized. I expect that this is the cause of the access violation error `0xC0000005`. For future reference, you would allocate and initialise these structs like so:

```
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = { sizeof StartupInfo };
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo = { 0 };
```

Then pass `&StartupInfo` and `&ProcessInfo` to `CreateProcess`. Of course, I'm just adding this advice for completeness. You'll be throwing away all the code relating to `CreateProcess` and calling `ShellExecuteEx` instead.

Comment: Thank you ver much for the reply. So I did change the lpApplicationName to the destination of an exe and getting same error. I also tried declaring pointers to structs but still closes unexpected.

Comment: Don't use `CreateProcess` to open a text file. Use `ShellExecuteEx`. If you have a new question, please ask it as such. Please don't expect a long debugging session via comments.

Comment: Okay thanks anyway, I couldn't get to work this function so I probably search for something else that doesn't involv system(); (PD: I did want to launch an .exe it. I just used the wrong example to post it lol)

Comment: That doesn't sound right at all. `CreateProcess` works fine. If you need to start an executable, you can use that. If you want to open a text file or indeed some other document type, use `ShellExecuteEx`. Don't just thrash around trying stuff at random and give up.

Comment: The code was almost right, now I can see the error: I was using single backslash \ and I had to use double \\. Btw: Thanks for your tip :)